# How to make table not overflow using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rangicus/au6joasv/) fiddle. It is used to learn information about a certain *Magic: The Gathering* card or set that you would like to learn about. If you were to type in `LEA` to the input then hit the *Find Set* button, it returns the info about the *Limited Edition Alpha* set. The only problem is that this doesn't keep the table within the window; the table spills over. If you type in `Sen Triplets` and hit *Find Card*, it returns the card info for *Sen Triplets*. This table stays within the window, how do I make the set one do this as well?

Comment: Your Fiddle won't work due to CORA issues.

Comment: The JSON files are not loading from a different domain.

Comment: I've updated it to work, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please consider creating a simpler fiddle with locally defined json that can actually demonstrate your issue.  The fiddle is still not running for me (as bpeterson mentioned, it is related to CORS, or Cross-Origin-Reference-Sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your display issue is occurring because the LEA "booster" data set is being interpreted as one long word.  Something like "common,common,common,..." is looked at by the browser as a single thing instead of multiple distinct words.  CSS handles this in most modern browsers using the word-break property.  [Here is one possible solution](https://jsfiddle.net/au6joasv/12/) where all that was changed is the CSS.  Because word-break allows the words to be wrapped to multiple lines, your table doesn't get screwed up anymore.  Additionally, a width had to be added to the rule because otherwise the left most column looks terrible.

```
tr, th, td { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-word;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

However, the REAL issue you're having is that you're trying to make an array (the booster data set) display as a string.  By default, it is joined together with just a comma when you try to force it to be a string.  If you handle the case when your data is an array [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/au6joasv/13/), you don't have to change the CSS at all... because you're allowing line breaks more easily since you no longer have one loooong word.

```
for(var i in set) if(i != "cards") {
    row = $("<tr>").appendTo(con);
    row.append($("<th>").text(i));
    if(typeof set[i] === 'string') {
        row.append($("<td>").text(set[i]));
        // note, you shouldn't assume everything in your data is ONLY a
        // string or an array... other cases should be handled.
    } else {
        // join arrays together with ", " instead of ","
        row.append($("<td>").text(set[i].join(", ")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did notice that others, possibly including you, edited my fiddle, and saved it. Is there any way to disable this?